# Communication between ViewModels via events

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an application where I open a new view (with viewmodel) within another viewmodel. The new Viewmodel needs some parameters from the caller viewmodel.

Now I introduced a class called Messenger which looks like:

```
public class Messenger
    {
        private static Messenger instance;
        public static Messenger Instance
        {
            get { return instance ?? (instance = new Messenger()); }
        }

        private Messenger() { }

        public void SendMessage(Message message)
        {
            OnMessageSent temp = MessageSent;
            if (temp != null)
                temp(message);
        }

        public delegate void OnMessageSent(Message message);
        public event OnMessageSent MessageSent;
    }
```

The message-class looks like:

```
public class Message
{
    public Type TargetType { get; set; }
    public object Sender { get; set; }
    public Type ValueType { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

The usage of this building is:

The receiver-viewmodel of a message has to add

`Messenger.Instance.MessageSent += MessageSent;`

to it's constructor. And in the implementation can look like:

```
 private void MessageSent(Message message)
 {
    if(message.TargetType == typeof(SecondViewModel))
    {
       if (message.ValueType == typeof (double))
          {
             this.MyValue= (double) message.Value;
          }
     }
  }
```

This works fine. My question is: Is this a good way for the communication between viewmodels or are there any weakenings in this design?

Comment: The 'canonical' approach to link up VM's is to use the Event Aggregator which is built in to Prism.  It uses a weakly coupled design that avoids the memory leaks associated with events.  You are sort of building a substitute version of it, but with a tightly coupled pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to re-invent the wheel when its already there.

Use [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) which internally uses [weak event pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx) to prevent any memory leaks. Refer to tutorials [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample) and [here](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2009/07/22/braindump-on-the-event-aggregator-pattern/).

Also you can use [Event Aggregator with Reactive Extensions](http://joseoncode.com/2010/04/29/event-aggregator-with-reactive-extensions/).

Refer to the post for viable approaches you can reuse - [Even Aggregator Implementation Sample/Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343980/event-aggregator-implementation-sample-best-practices).